# Smartwatch accelerometer accuracy issue

Tags: android, wear-os, wearables

I am using a smartwatch to capture sensor data and save it to a file.

The smartwatch is a Ticwatch E X8B1, with Wear OS 2.6, Google Play Services 15.0.90, Android 8.0.0.

I am developing the app using Android Studio 3.3.1 (Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788), JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64, JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o on Windows 10 10.0.

The app uses the a min SDK of 23, but the targeted one is 28.

It has the following dependencies:

```
com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1
com.android.support:percent:28.0.0
com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0
com.android.support:wear:28.0.0
com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0
```

Part of the code is as follows:

```
Sensor accelerometer = null;
accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

When the listener gets the information from the accelerometer, the accuracy code I get is 111 or 79. As far as I understand, it should be a value between -1 (SENSOR_STATUS_NO_CONTACT) and 3 (SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH).

What is happening? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: a data sample of when the watch was motionless on my desk

```
accuracy;timestamp;x;y;z
79;179275411989490;-2.1816406;2.0527344;9.484375
79;179275422089490;-2.2011719;2.0644531;9.5234375
79;179275432189490;-2.1894531;2.0546875;9.5078125
79;179275442289490;-2.1816406;2.0585938;9.46875
79;179275452389490;-2.1679688;2.0742188;9.5
79;179275462489490;-2.1816406;2.0683594;9.4921875
79;179275472589490;-2.1582031;2.0703125;9.4609375
79;179275482689490;-2.1660156;2.0703125;9.5
79;179275492789490;-2.1699219;2.078125;9.484375
79;179275502889490;-2.1679688;2.0644531;9.46875
79;179275512989490;-2.1757812;2.0546875;9.484375
79;179275523089490;-2.1699219;2.0800781;9.46875
79;179275533189490;-2.1640625;2.078125;9.484375
79;179275543289490;-2.1699219;2.0585938;9.4921875
79;179275553389490;-2.1679688;2.0488281;9.4921875
79;179275563489490;-2.1757812;2.0703125;9.4765625
79;179275573589490;-2.15625;2.0742188;9.453125
79;179275583689490;-2.1699219;2.0703125;9.5
79;179275593789490;-2.1875;2.046875;9.5078125
79;179275603889490;-2.1777344;2.0800781;9.484375
79;179275613989490;-2.1816406;2.0625;9.49
```

Comment: Perhaps the sensor supports a more granular accuracy? My intuition would be that everything equal/above 3 should be fine. When you are testing, are the values returned by the sensor believable?

Comment: I don't believe if has a more granular accuracy, but I really hope you are right. To be honest, as it is the first time I work with sensor data, I have no idea if the values returned by the sensor are beliavable. A sample of the values is:

accuracy;x;y;z
79;-2.1699219;2.0800781;9.46875
79;-2.1640625;2.078125;9.484375
79;-2.1699219;2.0585938;9.4921875
79;-2.1679688;2.0488281;9.4921875
79;-2.1757812;2.0703125;9.4765625

Another weird thing is that the watch was motionless on my desk and the values are changing. Shouldn't they be always the same in this condition?

Comment: I edited the question to add a bigger and readable data sample

Comment: The sensor will have slight inaccuracies which can be caused by magnetic interference for example. To check if the data is believable, move and turn it around. Check if the value lands in the same spot if you return it's position.